# Doctrine - Custom validators to locale

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I,m wondering if is there any possibility (in Doctrine2 or Symfony2) to configure custom validation depends on locale. What I want to do is to have different validators for postalcode for France, United Kingdom and Poland. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Idea #1:

It is possible, however, it requires a bit of coding, more than usual when it comes to validation.

You need to create custom `Constraint` and `Validator` which will be service and you will be able to inject `locale` into it.

For more info on how to add constraints see this [**link**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation).

### Idea #2

You need to add constraints directly to your form. Then inject `_locale` from your controller into the `Form` either via `__construct` or `options` array and you should be able to use it.